# Cómo pasar un objeto y recibirlo en una función Java

Tags: java, map

Estoy tratando de realizar el siguiente ejercicio de Codewars en Java:

https://www.codewars.com/kata/not-all-but-sometimes-all/csharp

El mandato es este:

> Escribir:
>
> **public static string Remove(string str, Dictionary what)**
>
> ***str*** toma una cadena y un objeto/dict/Diccionario ***what*** y devuelve una cadena con los caracteres eliminados en ***what***.

En C#, este debe ser el resultado del ejercício:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El hecho es que no se como pasar correctamente el siguiente parámetro al método que lo recibe:

```
Ideone.Remove("this is a string", new HashMap<Character, Integer>() { {'t', 1 }, {'i', 2 }});
```

A continuación dejo el código que tengo hasta ahora del ejercício, **la idea del ejercicio es que el método `Remove` devuelva el String `str` y los carateres especificados en `what` así como las veces que serán quitados**, por ejemplo:

```
Ideone.Remove("this is a string", new HashMap<Character, Integer>() { {'t', 1 }, {'i', 2 }});
```

Devolverá:

```
hs s a string
```

*por motivo de que no puedo pasar el parámetro no he probado la clase*, **les agradecería que si ven algo que consideran que puede mejorar me lo digan para así continuar aprendiendo y aplicando cambios a mi forma de programar.**

**Código del programa:**

```
import java.util.*;

class Ideone
{

public static String Remove(String str, Map<Character , Integer> what){

    // Definimos la vqariable retornada y una estructura de datos (hash table)
    // que contendra el caracter y las veces que será borrado de la cadena
    StringBuilder result = null;
    what= new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    // Bucle que recorre la cadena y va añadiendo las letras y sumando (borrando) las
    // coincidencias
    for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ ) {
        if ( what.containsKey ( str.charAt ( i ) ) ) {
            what.put ( str.charAt ( i ), what.remove ( str.charAt ( i ) ) + 1 );
        } else {
            what.put ( str.charAt ( i ), 1 );
        }
    }

    Set<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> freq = what.entrySet();

    Iterator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> it = freq.iterator();

    // Mostramos el resultado en la pantalla
    while ( it.hasNext() ) {
        Map.Entry<Character, Integer> item = it.next();
        result.append(str);

        System.out.println(item.getValue());
    }

    return result.toString();
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Ideone.Remove("this is a string", new HashMap<Character, Integer>() { {'t', 1 }, {'i', 2 }}); // --> "hs s a string"
    Ideone.Remove("hello world", new HashMap<Character, Integer>() { { 'x',5 }, {'i',2 }}); // --> "hello world"
    Ideone.Remove("apples and bananas", new HashMap<Character, Integer>() { {'a', 50 }, {'n', 1 }}); // --> "pples d bnns"
}

}
```

Da este **StackTrace** como resultado:

```
Main.java:42: error: not a statement
    CountLetters.Remove("this is a string", new HashMap<Character, Integer>() { {'t', 1 }, {'i', 2 }}); // --> "hs s a string"
                                                                                 ^
Main.java:42: error: ';' expected
    CountLetters.Remove("this is a string", new HashMap<Character, Integer>() { {'t', 1 }, {'i', 2 }}); // --> "hs s a string"
```

Si desean probar el código lo pueden encontrar en **Ideone** a través de este enlace:

[<kbd>ver demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/N2xWem)

***Muchas gracias de antemano.***

Comment: no entiendo que significa a:50

Comment: Disculpa, es que la única forma válida que conozco para hacer el ejercício, what es un objeto (object) según el mismo, así que lo declaré como **String**, había intentado hacerlo como Map pero no pude terminar la implementación, la idea no es que otro termine el ejercicio, sino que me den una explicación del mismo en dado caso esté mal

Comment: Si no son expresiones regulares entonces no se con especifidad que son exactamtente, quizás por eso no logro entender y terminar el ejercício

Comment: @DavidCalderon sigo sin entender a:50 y demas, 'n':1

Comment: **"{'t':1, 'i':2}"** la idea de este argumento, es que de cuantas **_i_  hayan debe de borrarse dos i** del String **_srt_**, cualquier letra especificada en este argumento sera borrada en **srt** cuantas veces se haya especificado, así **_a:50_** significa que borrará 50 ases del String **"apples and bananas"**, como esta horación no tiene 50 ases entonces borra todas las que tiene sin causar ningún error, por favor, dime si entendiste para explicarlo con algo mas de detalles.

Comment: @DavidCalderon solia solucionar problemas de jueces, y jamas vi que resolvieran con espresiones regulares, podrias resolverlo con tratamiento de cadenas

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias por tu buen consejo, pero lo que está especificado en `what` se me parece en algo a una expresión regular por su sintaxis quizás, entonces lo que me recoiendas es recorrer la `what` identificar la letra y borrar las coincidencias incluso con las llaves **{}** que podrían significar un arreglo.

Comment: Entiendo, pues eso es lo que sucede, a sinceridad nunca había escuchado es de diccionario en ningún sitio, solo en este ejercicio, pero siempre se aprende cosas nuevas, tocara investigar sobre eso pues, gracias @Mariano

Comment: Bueno, @Mariano no entiendo muy bien a lo que te refieres cuando hablas de tratar `t` y `I` como a objetos porque como tales deben ir dentro de un objetos Diccionario, **Map** en Java, pero sí, lo mejor es que edite la pregunta.

Comment: @DavidCalderon quizás esa debería ser tu primera pregunta: ¿Cómo pasar un objeto y recibirlo en tu función?

Comment: Ok, gracias @Mariano, editaré la pregunta tan pronto pueda.

Comment: @Mariano, pregunta editada

Comment: @DavidCalderon en la comunidad de codewars se puede crear clanes?

Comment: @x-rw no lo sé, solo veo los ejercicios que postean y trato de hacerlos con el motivo de desarrollar lógica y orientarme a la resolución de problemas que es lo que se basa la programación, no tengo cuenta creada